# How to get client DOM width in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, width, laravel-blade

I don't know if this is even possible, but I'd appreciate any help.

- How do I get the client's DOM width in Laravel?
- Basically, is there a way to extract the client's screen width from the `$request`?
- Or are there any functions in Laravel or Blade that will give me a screen width value?

I know that I can get the DOM width with jQuery `$(document).width()`, but I need the width value on server side; before any js is executed.

Comment: You can't do this. Closest thing I can think of is to redirect them from a page that just grabs this info and passes it to the server.

Comment: And in case you're wondering about why I need it: I am using http://Mun.ee on my server, which allows me to resize my images in real time, and if I know the client's screen width, I can serve the images pixel perfect (important for my scenario).

I know that I can also make ajax requests for the images once the page has loaded, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @Sturm I feared as much :(
But thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ArturGrigio You can try set [JavaScript cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)  and access it in `Laravel`. When user visits your website, get the screen size with JS (`window.width`) and store it in a cookie `screen=WxH`
In Laravel `$screen = Cookie::get('screen');`

```
$screen = explode("x", $screen);
$width = $screen[0]
$height = $screen[0];
```

This is 1 solution to do it.

Unfortunately the is no way to get screen size info from PHP. 
You can try to play around with User Agent and detect if it is a mobile or desktop or tablet. and make fix sizes for those 3 types.

A good [User Agent package for Laravel](https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect)

Comment: Thanks, that's a smart approach, but what about the very first request, before the cookie is even set?

Comment: @ArturGrigio The only ways is ajax, so when user comes to your website  if he doesn't have a cookie (check in php or js) , you don't load any images, and send an ajax request with new setted cookie to set width and height, after that load all images. And it should be even faster. This is the only what I can think right now.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been searching the internet for the past hour, and I didn’t find anything better than hacks and tricks. I didn't even find a good Node.js cross-OS, cross-Browser package to solve this problem...

But to anyone that has a similar question, here is my workaround (even though I still think there might be a better way to achieve the desired outcome, like @Froxz).

**Possible Solution:**
I used an awesome lazy-load library by [Ress.io](https://github.com/ressio) called [LazyLoadXT](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt).

Here is a standard img html tag:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5coxi.jpg" width="300px">
```

Here it is with *LazyLoadXT*:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/dist/jquery.lazyloadxt.js"></script>
</head>
<img data-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5coxi.jpg" width="300px" src="">
```

And here it is with *LazyLoadXT* + JavaScript:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/dist/jquery.lazyloadxt.js"></script>
</head>
<script>document.write('<img data-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5coxi.jpg" width="' + document.documentElement.clientWidth + 'px" src="">')</script>
```

This is still ajax (which I was trying to avoid), but it is the cleanest solution I was able to think of.

DEMO: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arturgrigio/huwxyq2v/)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using **Livewire** and **AlpineJS**.

In your blade view:

```
x-init="$wire.getScreenWidth(window.innerWidth)"
```

Within the corresponding Livewire Component Class:

```
public function getScreenWidth($width)
{
    // do stuff with $width;

}
```

[AlpineJS x-init](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init)

[Calling Livewire methods](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/alpine#calling-livewire-methods)